# Bash function with printf output missing formatting only sometimes

Tags: bash, shell, printf, string-formatting

I have a function that takes four parameters and outputs a formatted heading. Most of the time this function works, but occasionally it decides to not.

```
yelB=$'\e[1;33m'
fclr=$'\e[0m'

format_title() {
    # USAGE
    #   format_title "TITLE" "{h1/h2/h3}" "${color}" "{fill_character}"
    # EXMAPLE
    #   format_title "Heading 1" "h2" "$yelB" "="
    #   ============================ Heading 1 ============================

    ftitle=$1
    heading=$2
    color=$3
    fill=$4

    total_length=100
    ftitle_spacing=" "
    ftitle_border=$'\n' # variable implemented in h1 instances only
    formatted_ftitle=""

    if [[ $heading == "h1" ]]; then
        for (( i=1; i<=$total_length; i++ )); do
            ftitle_border=$ftitle_border$fill
        done
    fi

    if [[ $heading == "h1" || $heading == "h2" ]]; then
        ftitle_spacing="          "
    fi

    ftitle_fill=$(( ( $total_length / 2 ) - ( ${#ftitle} / 2 ) - ${#ftitle_spacing} ))

    for (( i=0; i<=$ftitle_fill; i++ )); do
        formatted_ftitle=$formatted_ftitle$fill

        if (( i == $ftitle_fill - 1 )); then

            formatted_ftitle=$formatted_ftitle$ftitle_spacing$color$ftitle$fclr$ftitle_spacing$formatted_ftitle

            # Check if the fill will be even or odd; if odd, remove the last fill character
            if (( $ftitle_fill % 2 )); then
                formatted_ftitle="${formatted_ftitle::-1}"
            fi

            if [[ $heading == "h1" ]]; then
                formatted_ftitle=$ftitle_border$'\n'$formatted_ftitle$ftitle_border$'\n'
            fi

            break
        fi
    done

    printf "%s\n" "$formatted_ftitle"
}

format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h1" "$yelB" "#"
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h1" "$yelB" "#"
format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h2" "$yelB" "="
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h2" "$yelB" "="
format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h3" "$yelB" "-"
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h3" "$yelB" "-"
```

[Shell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBGV.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBGV.png]
The idea is that all headings line up to a max of 100 characters with a fill character for titles with less than 100 characters.

As you can see, some headings don't line up; though trivial, it's very annoying (ignore the uncoloured heading -- a variable was misnamed when I printed the output).

I can't figure out what's causing the issue of some of the headings. Is it a character interpretation error with Bash when concatenating strings?

Comment: what do you mean by 'line up'? all 'TEST' strings start in same column? w/ same number of leading '#=<space>' ?  Since all the strings appear to be 'off' by 1 character, I'd guess there's a logic error regarding the calculation of `ftitle_fill`, ie, bash math is integer based so I'm wondering if you're not properly handling the truncated 0.5 when halving the length of the odd length strings? have you tried printing `${ftitle_fill}` and the length of `formatted_ftitle` (`${#formatted_ftitle}`) to see if the numbers match up with what you're expecting?

Comment: @markp You can see on the embedded image that the output of the last two headings are short and extended by one fill character respectively. The math seems fine as the image also shows variable heading lengths (one with an even number of characters and one for an odd number, which the function accommodates for).

Comment: you haven't defined 'line up'; from my perspective everything should be left justified, with the same number of leading '#=-<space>'... in addition to the issue with the trailing 1-3 characters of the last 3 lines; again,since everything appears to be 'off' by 1 character ... I'm still betting your math is not correct regarding the truncated 0.5 ... again, modify the script to print the actual numbers and see if they match what you expect

Comment: @markp sorry -- I just realised that. By 'line-up', I mean that each heading should be inline with their last fill character; having a total length of 100 characters. The titles are aligned right-justified, which I understand why and am happy with. But the last two headings in the image are short and extended by 1 fill character as well as being right-justified -- and that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: ANSI Color codes count in string indexing but are not displayed

Comment: @LéaGris As they're all the same color, it doesn't make much sense that only two of the six headings would have the incorrect amount of fill characters, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For h1/h2 you have `${#formatted_ftitle} = 18/19` for even/odd `${#ftitle}`, respectively (ie, even=even, odd=odd).

But for h3 you have `${#formatted_ftitle} = 27/28` for even/odd `${#ftitle}`, respectively (ie, odd=even, even=odd).

So, it looks like you need to take into consideration not only the odd/even-ness of the filler but also the title ... when determining if you should strip off a trailing character.

Actually, it looks like it boils down to just having to worry about the even/odd-ness of `${#ftitle}`, eg:

```
yelB=$'\e[1;33m'
fclr=$'\e[0m'

format_title() {
    # USAGE
    #   format_title "TITLE" "{h1/h2/h3}" "${color}" "{fill_character}"
    # EXMAPLE
    #   format_title "Heading 1" "h2" "$yelB" "="
    #   ============================ Heading 1 ============================

    ftitle=$1
    heading=$2
    color=$3
    fill=$4

    total_length=100
    ftitle_spacing=" "
    ftitle_border=$'\n' # variable implemented in h1 instances only
    formatted_ftitle=""

    if [[ $heading == "h1" ]]; then
        for (( i=1; i<=$total_length; i++ )); do
            ftitle_border=$ftitle_border$fill
        done
    fi

    if [[ $heading == "h1" || $heading == "h2" ]]; then
        ftitle_spacing="          "
    fi

    ftitle_fill=$(( ( $total_length / 2 ) - ( ${#ftitle} / 2 ) - ${#ftitle_spacing} ))

    for (( i=0; i<$ftitle_fill; i++ )); do
        formatted_ftitle=$formatted_ftitle$fill
    done

    formatted_ftitle=$formatted_ftitle$ftitle_spacing$color$ftitle$fclr$ftitle_spacing$formatted_ftitle

    # if the length of ftitle is odd, remove the last fill character

    if (( ${#ftitle} % 2 )); then
        formatted_ftitle="${formatted_ftitle::-1}"
    fi


    if [[ $heading == "h1" ]]; then
        formatted_ftitle=$ftitle_border$'\n'$formatted_ftitle$ftitle_border$'\n'
    fi

    printf "%s\n" "${formatted_ftitle}"
}

format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h1" "$yelB" "#"
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h1" "$yelB" "#"
format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h2" "$yelB" "="
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h2" "$yelB" "="
format_title "TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h3" "$yelB" "-"
format_title "TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS" "h3" "$yelB" "-"

####################################################################################################
##################          TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS          ##################
####################################################################################################


####################################################################################################
###################          TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS          ##################
####################################################################################################

==================          TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS          ==================
===================          TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS          ==================
--------------------------- TEST HEADING ONE WITH EVEN NUMBER CHARACTERS ---------------------------
---------------------------- TEST HEADING TWO WITH ODD NUMBER CHARACTERS ---------------------------
```

Comment: `h1` and `h2` have an even number of whitespaces between the fill characters and the title string, `h3` has one whitespace. Adding an extra whitespace to `h3` fixed this. Thanks so much!